# How to bypass shutdown dialog in windows xp

Tags: windows-xp

Is it possible to somehow bypass the shutdown dialog and shutdown windows xp just like windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a shortcut for `shutdown -s -t 0` and add it to the Start menu.

Or press <kbd>Win</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd>.

Comment: The shortcut would be in .bat format?

Comment: I would choose .lnk myself, for adding a nice icon, but .bat/.cmd will work too.